# How to retrieve sql table records for specified date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server table where Employee information is stored.It has DOB column;now i want to find all the employees who are born in month of jan to march of same year (for e.g. 2014-Jan-02 to 2014- March-02).Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define same year ? Do you want to count the employees born the same year in jan to march or do you just want the employes born jan to march 2014 (I imagine this number will be 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from tablename
where Month(DOB) between 1 and 3
```

Comment: this will include jan to march for all years and having a function on a field is not good for performance

Comment: Yes you are right, but i assume that he want to find birth days of employees to say them happy birth day!

Comment: thats right;I wanted to find all employees who are born between jan to march